# Can we add images into outlook mail using php?

Tags: php

I have a Create task page. So once Task is created, and if user admin clicks mail button. Outlook will open and add the subject and body which I typed.

But my doubt is can I add an image and also can we change teh font color in Message using code itself. I am a newbie in this thats why the dumb doubt.

```
<a href="mailto:xxxx@xxxx.com?subject=Any Subject&body= Any Topics">Mail</a>>
```

Comment: You will not be able to add an image through a `mailto:` link. How do you mean changing the font color of the subject?

Comment: Consider using something like SwiftMailer - it'll make HTML email composition easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is just an email application, which shows email as it appears.

#### There is no such thing as Outlook Compatible email.

You should provide direct link to images where you are sending a HTML email. Here is simple example of doing this using native `mail()`<sup>*[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)*</sup> function.

```
<?php
$subject = 'Email with image';
$message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Email with image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p><img src="http://mydomain.com/direct/link/toimage.jpg" /></p>
    </body>
    </html>';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
//..................

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every email client application works differently.
Second, You can't change the subject font.
As for adding images on the e-mail, you must attach headers to the mail being sent, indicating it contains html data. Then you must add the image itself either as an attached file or adding the html img tag on the mail body. I'd rather use the php `mail()` function, but you have [here](http://shadow2531.com/opera/testcases/mailto/modern_mailto_uri_scheme.html) and [here](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/rfc2368.txt) some specifications to work with `mailto`, which is rather obscene.

Comment: Can you show me an example, how to do that using mail function like when user clicks a button mail to open outlook and send mail, like mailto functions does.

Comment: If you want to work with outlook, you have to use `mailto`. Using PHP's `mail()` function requires users to send mails via a PHP application.